# How to use define to load node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs, node-modules

I am trying to use node modules in my requirejs module. Other parts of project use requirejs modules. Specifically, I am trying to use semantic-ui-react. On requirejs website https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2 , it said the following. How do I use this if I'm using define([],()=>{}) instead of require as shown in the example.

```js
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
    //function to requirejs so that node modules
    //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['foo', 'bar'],
function   (foo,   bar) {
    //foo and bar are loaded according to requirejs
    //config, but if not found, then node's require
    //is used to load the module.
});
```

Comment: Do you want to use the NodeJS module in the Browser (frontend) or do you want to use RequireJS in NodeJS (backend)?

Comment: I want to use NodeJS modules in the Browser

Comment: So you should check this out https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#packages :)

Comment: Thank you. I think I was reading the wrong section. The above section was for using node modules in requirejs *On server side*. I think it doesn't apply in my case because "require" in the first line is from Node and it's not defined in the server

Comment: RequireJS site is quiet old and it is not so obvious...